Free up local checkpoint memory
I am writing an iterative algorithm and I am using localCheckpoint to break the dataframe lineage as well as to persist the data for next iteration. The problem is unpersist doesn't seem to work on local checkpointed dataframe, and thus the local checkpointed dataframe is never cleared (the storage UI also confirms that).
The following code illustrates the iterate algorithm:
result = empty_dataframe()

while condition: 
  df = load_partition(dt)
  old_result = result
  result = process_partition(old_result, df).localCheckpoint()
  old_result.unpersist() # doesn't seem to work as intented


I believe unpersist only works for cache and persist but I didn't find any resources on how to clear local checkpointed dataframe.

We can notice the old checkpointed dataframes are evicted to disk but never evicted.
